# parsing JSON result in javascript when response is not in array

Tags: javascript, json

When making a Javascript API call, I get my results back like this:

```
{
"data": {
    "2 Broke Girls": {
        "air_by_date": 0, 
        "cache": {
            "banner": 1, 
            "poster": 1
        }, 
        "language": "en", 
        "network": "CBS", 
        "next_ep_airdate": "2014-02-24", 
        "paused": 0, 
        "quality": "HD", 
        "show_name": "2 Broke Girls", 
        "status": "Continuing", 
        "tvdbid": 248741, 
        "tvrage_id": 28416, 
        "tvrage_name": "2 Broke Girls"
    }, 
    "Alias": {
        ...
    },
    "message": "", 
    "result": "success"
    }
}
```

How can i successfully iterate through all the different shows that are being returned ? I can't use `response.data.SHOWNAME` because the shows will be changing around alot.

I tried a couple of solutions using `$.each()` but i didn't really get those to work. 
I can get as far as accessing each show title on it's own, but the other data keeps getting returned as being `[Object object]`

Edit: To make it a little bit clearer, i need access to the field. 
    response.data.RANDOM_TITLE.tvrage_name & response.data.RANDOM_TITLE.status

Comment: +1 for having Alias on that list.

Comment: How do you know that "message" is not a show? Because it's not an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me too!

```
function getShows (json) {

    // grab just the data part
    var data = JSON.parse(json).data,
        i,

        // empty array for your shows
        shows = [];

    // delete the crap you don't want
    delete data.message;
    delete data.result;

    // loop through everything else
    for (i in data) {

        // make sure it's an own property
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(i)) {

            // add to you collection of shows
            shows.push(data[i]);
        }
    }

    // tada
    return shows;
}
```

Comment: got it to work based on this, i owe you a beer or a cookie... your choice.

Comment: @Crimson document.cookie = "flavor=beer";

Answer (score 0):

You can access the data like :

```
for(var show_name in response.data) {
    var show = response.data[show_name];
    if(!(show instanceof Object)) continue;
    console.log(show_name, show); 
    //note that not all browsers will print the "show" object, 
    //IE will just say [object]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (name in data) {
   if (data.hasOwnProperty(name)){
      //code here
      //make sure to ignore message and result and any other special results returned. 
      showDetails = data[name];
   }
}
```

Where data here is the returned response.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the returned data into a variable.

```
eg

var jsonData = data;
for(var i=0;t<=jsonData.length;i++){
    console.log(jsonData[i].data);
}
```

Comment: even better. just take the jsonData[0] with your json items

Answer (score 0):

You can access like this:

```
var dkeys = Object.keys(d.data);
for (var i=0; i < dkeys.length; i++) {
    if (typeof d.data[dkeys[i]].show_name !== 'undefined') {
        alert(d.data[dkeys[i]].show_name);
    }
}
```